# How can I render the .aspx with initial values, but continue to run a conditional statement in the code behind and redirect upon completion?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Here is what I have...

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        if (Request.QueryString["Id"] != null)
        {
            int iID = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["Id"].ToString());
            WaitForRequest(iID);
        }
    }
}
public void WaitForRequest(int id)
{
    SqlParameter[] sqlParms = new SqlParameter[1];
    sqlParms[0] = new SqlParameter("@ID", id);
    int iStatus = Convert.ToInt32(DBManager.SqlHelper.ExecuteScalar(connString, CommandType.StoredProcedure, "[dbo].[Proc]", sqlParms).ToString());

    if (iStatus < 3)
    {
        do
        {
            tbLaunchStatus.Text = iStatus.ToString();

            Thread.Sleep(500);

            iStatus = Convert.ToInt16(DBManager.SqlHelper.ExecuteScalar(connString, CommandType.StoredProcedure, "[dbo].[Proc]", sqlParms).ToString());
        } while (iStatus < 3);
    }
}
```

Basically, upon redirecting to this page, I would like to render the page with the initial values, and continue to run the conditional do/while in the code behind until it returns a value that I am waiting for. Then it will redirect. Currently, the referring page is displayed until the conditional loop is met in this page, and then this page is displayed with the final values. I know there is AJAX stuff for this, but this is on an legacy program, and AJAX is not currently involved. Thoughts?

Comment: You need to use AJAX.

Comment: That's what I thought. Just seeing if there was any other way. Do you have an example for me to use in this case?

Comment: Google has one or two [thousand] for you.

Answer (score 0):

Directly, you need AJAX.

Without AJAX, you can split the logic in two parts.
Make a function of the logic that you want to run in back ground. And when the page gets loaded, do a postback to that function via JS.